# Not getting time from timezone.now in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My django model field is:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(
    default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

And when I run 'now()' in the interpreter from my app, I get:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 18, 15, 38, 7, 442631, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

but if I look in my database, I see (and return) only dates, not times, such like

```
2018-02-19
```

This is an inherited app, and despite a great deal of searching, I can't find anything that might be setting this to date only.

Comment: what does your postgres schema look like for the `created_at` column?

Comment: What timezone has your server?

Comment: What do you get when using `timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()`

Comment: How do you create your object?

Comment: In Django I would use `auto_now=True` or `auto_now_add=True` depending on your intention instead of defaulting to `django.utils.timezone.now`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [most certainly want to do this instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I this does not work, you may check if your database schema matches the model. One way to do this is to use the `inspectdb`:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > inspected_models.py
```

Then compare the Model from `models.py` with the model for the same table at `inspected_models.py`; check if the columns are of the same type.